# How to create a vector of vectors in Scheme?

Tags: vector, scheme, implementation, srfi

How do you create a vector of vectors in scheme, and how can change the input on a certain event?

I am aware of the existence of SRFI25, which allows you to do just that, but I'm interest to see the implementation, as well as the result.

Comment: You might enjoy the [matrices](http://programmingpraxis.com/standard-prelude/#matrices) at my blog, which were stolen from [Kent Dybvig](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/examples.html#./examples:h1).

Comment: Thank you. I think I can make use of that.

Answer (score 2):

This will create an immutable vector:

```
'#(#(1 2 3) #(4 5 6))
```

And this will create a mutable vector, with the same structure:

```
(vector (vector 1 2 3) (vector 4 5 6))
```

Comment: `'#(#(1 2 3) #(4 5 6))` would be considered a constant and thus immutable. You also have `make-vector`.